# Mongoose find() RegExp for Number type field

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb

I'm try to create a table with filters and when i need find rows through regular expression i have error below.
How i can use RegExp with field type of Number? Change field type on String, is a good idea?

```
var ContractSchema = new Schema({
  userId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  number: Number,
  // ...
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Contract', ContractSchema);

Contract.find({number: /555/}, function(err, contracts){
  console.log(err, contracts);
});
```

> Cast to number failed for value "/555/" at path "number"

Comment: Try this `{number: { $regex: /555/ } }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well regular expressions only work on strings of course. You could however still do this, though it's highly inefficient to do so:

```js
Contract.find(
    { "$where": "function() { return this.number.toString().match(/555/) != null; }" }
).function(err,contracts) {
   // do something with results
});
```

The MongoDB [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) query operator allows for a JavaScript condition to be evaluated on the server for each document in the collection or those left from other query conditions.

Basically that evaluation converts the field value to a `String` and then allows a regex operation on it.

Otherwise, you change your content or add another field for a string representation. But unless you are using an anchor `^` from the start of the string, then even a `$regex` operation on an actual string field is barely more efficient than using the JavaScript evaluation as shown.

P.S Make sure your server allows JavaScript evaluation. Some people choose to turn this off. But it should be on by default.

Comment: Thanks, for this answer. It is helped me.
Contract.find({
 "$where" : "/555/.test(this.number)"
}, function(err, contracts){
 console.log(err, contracts);
});

Comment: @ЕвгенийКуманин Of course you use `.test`. I just had `.match` on the brain. Suppose it's how you look at it LHS to RHS, but it's a worthwhile note.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use `$where` (i.e. if you use `mongoose-paginate-v2`) then replace `$where` with `$expr`:

```js
const fieldName = 'number'
const regExp = new RegExp(555);

const query = {
  $expr: {
    $regexMatch: {
      input: { $toString: `$${fieldName}` },
      regex: regExp,
    },
};

Contract.find(query);
```

Answer (score -1):

Either convert your `number` to type string for each document, and then you can use Regular Expressions properly and efficiently, or just give up on using RegEx's, and use the built in Mongo filtering options instead.

For example, to find a number with a particular value:

```
{number: 555}
```

Or to find a number in the range (500, 600):

```
{number: {$gt: 500, $lt: 600}}
```

Here is a [list of some common query operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/).

Either of these is more efficient than converting each `Number` to a `String` at query time.

Comment: I think the concept here was looking for part of a number as in `111555333`, which of course does not respond to a range query to find `555`