# Use regex for numbers with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get matching trainNos from DB.
This is what I have tried.

```js
var query = trainList.find((req.query.trainNo === '') ? {} : { trainNo: { $regex: req.query.trainNo } });
        query.paginate(options, function(err, response) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            res.json(response);
        })
```

But i get an error saying cant use regex with number.
Also I tried this link [Mongoose find() RegExp for Number type field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722650/mongoose-find-regexp-for-number-type-field)

still getting the same error.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the value of `req.query.trainNo`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var query = trainList.find((req.body.trainNo === '') ? {} : { trainNo : new RegExp(req.body.trainNo, 'i') });
        query.paginate(options, function(err, response) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            res.json(response);
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

As the linked answer suggested, you could use the **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** operator but is highly inefficient and not recommended:

```
var criteria = (req.body.trainNo === '') ? {} : { "$where" : "/"+req.body.trainNo+"/.test(this.trainNo)" };
trainList.find(criteria).paginate(options, function(err, response) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    res.json(response);
});
```