# $regex is not working with integer value field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i tried to search data using `$regex` with mongoose but its not working with Number field.

here is my model.js

```
var transactionsSchema = new Schema({
    user : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    amount : {type : Number}
});
```

here is my query

```
var condition = {
  user:user,
  amount:{ $regex: search}
};

Model.find(condition)..exec(function(err,res){
console.log(res);
});
```

i getting following error

```
Can't use $regex with Number.
```

then tried the following

```
var condition = {
      user:user,
      amount:{ "$where": "function() { return this.amount.toString().match(/"+search+"/) != null; }" }
    };

    Model.find(condition)..exec(function(err,res){
    console.log(res);
    });
```

its given following

```
Error: Can't use $where with Number.
```

now i changed my condition like this

```
var condition = {
          user:user
        }
        condition["$where"] = "function() { return this.amount.toString().match(/"+search+"/) != null; }";

        Model.find(condition)..exec(function(err,res){
        console.log(res); //output []
        });
```

its worked in `mongo` shell with accurate result but in `mongoose` query its return empty array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose find() RegExp for Number type field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722650/mongoose-find-regexp-for-number-type-field)

Comment: i tried that but its still give that error

Comment: The error message described exactly the issue. Regular expressions is a text matching method. You cannot use it on Numbers.

Comment: so which is alternative of regex ?